# how to extract the vlaues from this XML file using python parsers

Tags: xml, database, python-2.7, parsing

Am new to python.
    Now i want to extract values from XML.
    OS: ubnutu linux
    language:pyhton
    I want to take vlaues from this file.
    eg:
    module name: Test_case_1
    yang-version value: 1
    ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="Test_case_1"
        xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:yin:1"
        xmlns:test="test1:level1:newlevel">
  <yang-version value="1"/>
  <namespace uri="test1:level1:newlevel"/>
  <prefix value="test"/>
  <organization>
    <text>huawei</text>
  </organization>
  <contact>
    <text>adarsh.m@huawei.com</text>
  </contact>
  <description>
    <text>test</text>
  </description>
  <revision date="2015-02-12"/>
  <leaf-list name="domain-search">
    <type name="string"/>
    <description>
      <text>List of domain names to search</text>
    </description>
  </leaf-list>
  <container name="cont1">
    <leaf name="adarsh1">
      <type name="string"/>
    </leaf>
  </container>
  <container name="cont2">
    <leaf name="leaf2-to">
      <type name="string"/>
    </leaf>
  </container>
</module>
```

Comment: May be you want to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('your_xml_file.xml')
module_node = root.find('.//module')
yang_version_node = root.find('.//yang-version')
```

Now `module_node.attrib` and `yang_version_node.attrib` are dictionaries so

```
print module_node.attrib['name'] # Test_case_1
print yang_version_node.attrib['value'] # 1
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
import shutil
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
infile = open("movies.xml","r")
root = ET.parse('movies.xml')
print root.find('module')
module_node = root.find('module')
yang_version_node = root.find('.//yang-version')
print module_node.attrib['name']  
print yang_version_node.attrib['value'] 

output:
<open file 'movies.xml', mode 'r' at 0x7f8984b4cc00>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/root1/YANG/stack_help.py", line 19, in <module>
    print module_node.attrib['name']  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: <open file 'movies.xml', mode 'r' at 0x7f8984b4cc00>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/root1/YANG/stack_help.py", line 19, in <module>
    print module_node.attrib['name']  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: you don't need to open the xml file. Just pass the path to the xml file as string input to  ET.parse()